# Best JSON parser for Qt?

Tags: json, parsing, qt

I'm using QT for Symbian and need a simple json parser. I need to be able to go from json to Qt-variant and the other way around. Is there a simple json parser that I can use? I don't want to write my own.

Comment: Qt5 comes with a JSON parser in QtCore. For Qt 4, you can backport it.

Answer (score 26):

You need no Additional code except QT itself to parse JSON with QT

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html

Comment: This is really evaluating JavaScript, which may not be ideal from either a performance or security point of view.

Comment: Matthew: The JSON RFC includes a simple regex-based check at the end to determine whether JSON is safe for evaluation by a JavaScript engine.

Comment: Joey, it does, but for mobile app loading the javascript engine is undesirable.

Answer (score 20):

Check out [Qt-Json](https://github.com/ereilin/qt-json)

Its a dead-simple class for parsing and serializing JSON data.

Comment: There is now a bunch of differences, such that *exactly* no longer applies.

Comment: True, edited that part away.

Comment: GPL License. This is too much for just a JSON parser.

Answer (score 16):

The [**qjson**](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/) project may be a good start. It has also been packaged for [Debian](http://www.debian.org).

Comment: qjson is the kind of heavy weight library that I avoid at all cost in my projects. It needs to be built and installed separately for each system and forces you to distribute a new DLL with your executable. Depending on your needs, it's much better to use the buit-in way proposed by ALoopingIcon, or Eelis's QJson class, which is great too (http://ereilin.tumblr.com/post/6857765046/json-parser-class-for-qt).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a QLALR based JSON parser : http://git.forwardbias.in/?p=qjsonparser.git.

git clone git://git.forwardbias.in/qjsonparser.git.