# How to serialize to JSON in Qt

Tags: c++, json, qt, serialization, qjson

How can I JSON serialize a QVariant (or other type of data) in Qt. 
I don't want to use an external third party library like [QJson](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Related → http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893040/how-to-create-read-write-json-files-in-qt5

Answer (score 22):

Just to mention, as of Qt5, JSON is officially supported:

[JSON Support in Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/json.html)

```
QVariant id(1), name("John Doe");
QJsonObject json;

json["Name"] = name.toString();
json.insert("id", id.toInt());
```

Comment: But, how to stract a JSON string from it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181627/how-to-convert-a-qjsonobject-to-qstring

Answer (score 5):

[Parsing JSON with QT using standard QT library](https://web.archive.org/web/20130111091817/http://qtwiki.remdex.info/Parsing_JSON_with_QT_using_standard_QT_library).

BTW: why don't you want to use QJson? It nicely encapsulates all the QScriptValueIterator stuff, making your code easier to read.

Comment: @BojanKogoj It still exists here: https://web.archive.org/web/20130111091817/http://qtwiki.remdex.info/Parsing_JSON_with_QT_using_standard_QT_library

Answer (score -6):

There are no internal tools in Qt to do it. You will have to use a lib.
Or roll your own implementation

Comment: nowadays is this answer no longer valid, there is a QJsonObject class