# How to create/read/write JSON files in Qt5

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5

Qt5 has a new JSON parser and I want to use it. The problem is that it isn't too clear about what the functions do in layman's terms and how to write code with it. That or I could be reading it wrong.

I want to know the code on creating a JSON file in Qt5 and what "encapsulates" mean.

Comment: http://qjson.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Min Lin: QJson is sort of outdated with Qt5 (not sure it's even ported), as it brings its own Json implementation. Jim Kieger: What have you tried?

Comment: [This reference page](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qjsondocument.html) has the QJsonDocument::QJsonDocument() and 
QJsonDocument::QJsonDocument(const QJsonDocument & other) functions.  I've tried QJsonDocument but it doesn't seem to create anything.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

**Example: Read json from file**

```
/* test.json */
{
   "appDesc": {
      "description": "SomeDescription",
      "message": "SomeMessage"
   },
   "appName": {
      "description": "Home",
      "message": "Welcome",
      "imp":["awesome","best","good"]
   }
}


void readJson()
   {
      QString val;
      QFile file;
      file.setFileName("test.json");
      file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
      val = file.readAll();
      file.close();
      qWarning() << val;
      QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val.toUtf8());
      QJsonObject sett2 = d.object();
      QJsonValue value = sett2.value(QString("appName"));
      qWarning() << value;
      QJsonObject item = value.toObject();
      qWarning() << tr("QJsonObject of description: ") << item;

      /* in case of string value get value and convert into string*/
      qWarning() << tr("QJsonObject[appName] of description: ") << item["description"];
      QJsonValue subobj = item["description"];
      qWarning() << subobj.toString();

      /* in case of array get array and convert into string*/
      qWarning() << tr("QJsonObject[appName] of value: ") << item["imp"];
      QJsonArray test = item["imp"].toArray();
      qWarning() << test[1].toString();
   }
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
QJsonValue(object, QJsonObject({"description": "Home","imp": ["awesome","best","good"],"message": "YouTube"}) ) 
"QJsonObject of description: " QJsonObject({"description": "Home","imp": ["awesome","best","good"],"message": "YouTube"}) 
"QJsonObject[appName] of description: " QJsonValue(string, "Home") 
"Home" 
"QJsonObject[appName] of value: " QJsonValue(array, QJsonArray(["awesome","best","good"]) ) 
"best"
```

---

**Example: Read json from string**

Assign json to string as below and use the `readJson()` function shown before:

```
val =   
'  {
       "appDesc": {
          "description": "SomeDescription",
          "message": "SomeMessage"
       },
       "appName": {
          "description": "Home",
          "message": "Welcome",
          "imp":["awesome","best","good"]
       }
    }';
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
QJsonValue(object, QJsonObject({"description": "Home","imp": ["awesome","best","good"],"message": "YouTube"}) ) 
"QJsonObject of description: " QJsonObject({"description": "Home","imp": ["awesome","best","good"],"message": "YouTube"}) 
"QJsonObject[appName] of description: " QJsonValue(string, "Home") 
"Home" 
"QJsonObject[appName] of value: " QJsonValue(array, QJsonArray(["awesome","best","good"]) ) 
"best"
```

Comment: I found this really good example a bright shiny star of hope and have followed the example to the letter.  However, when I debug the example, the values of the entries are showing as null.  Is this the only example "step by step" on how to create, read and write a JSON file in QT?  I can't figure out what I might be doing wrong.  Using QT Creator 3.0.1.  Thanks

Comment: @Shawn In the Help tab in QT Creator, search for JSON Save Game Example. This pretty much demonstrates everything one needs to do to read and write JSON values (including arrays). [JSON Save Game Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcore-savegame-example.html)

Comment: You could skip converting utf-8  bytes to utf-16 and back (QString, `toUtf8()`) if you use `QByteArray` instead.

Comment: Load whole file to string and then parse the string, really?!

Comment: I was having trouble with this until I checked the optional error parameter: 
`QJsonParseError err;
QByteArray utf8String = jsonString.toUtf8();
QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(utf8String, &err);`

Comment: How to create/read/write JSon files in Qt5 is not answered - at least today is there just a read example or am I wrong?

Comment: If I compile SQLite3 with the JSON1 extension, can I use the JSON1 extension in Qt 4.10?

Answer (score 4):

JSON under QT is actually quite pleasant - I was surprised. This is an example of how to create a JSON output with some structure.

Forgive me for not explaining what the fields all mean - it is a Ham Radio processing output script.

This is the QT C++ Code

```
void CabrilloReader::JsonOutputMapper()
{
  QFile file(QDir::homePath() + "/1.json");
  if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
      qDebug() << "File open error";
    } else {
      qDebug() <<"JSONTest2 File open!";
    }

  // Clear the original content in the file
  file.resize(0);

  // Add a value using QJsonArray and write to the file
  QJsonArray jsonArray;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      QJsonObject jsonObject;
      CabrilloRecord *rec= QSOs.at(i);
      jsonObject.insert("Date", rec->getWhen().toString());
      jsonObject.insert("Band", rec->getBand().toStr());
      QJsonObject jsonSenderLatObject;
      jsonSenderLatObject.insert("Lat",rec->getSender()->fLat);
      jsonSenderLatObject.insert("Lon",rec->getSender()->fLon);
      jsonSenderLatObject.insert("Sender",rec->getSender_call());
      QJsonObject jsonReceiverLatObject;
      jsonReceiverLatObject.insert("Lat",rec->getReceiver()->fLat);
      jsonReceiverLatObject.insert("Lon",rec->getReceiver()->fLon);
      jsonReceiverLatObject.insert("Receiver",rec->getReceiver_call());
      jsonObject.insert("Receiver",jsonReceiverLatObject);
      jsonObject.insert("Sender",jsonSenderLatObject);
      jsonArray.append(jsonObject);
      QThread::sleep(2);
    }

  QJsonObject jsonObject;
  jsonObject.insert("number", jsonArray.size());
  jsonArray.append(jsonObject);

  QJsonDocument jsonDoc;
  jsonDoc.setArray(jsonArray);
  file.write(jsonDoc.toJson());
  file.close();
  qDebug() << "Write to file";
}
```

It takes an internal QT Structure (a List of pointers to a CabrilloRecord object ... which you just ignore) and extracts some fields. These fields are then output in a nested JSON format which looks like this.

```
[
    {
        "Band": "20",
        "Date": "Sat Jul 10 12:00:00 2021",
        "Receiver": {
            "Lat": 36.400001525878906,
            "Lon": 138.3800048828125,
            "Receiver": "8N3HQ       "
        },
        "Sender": {
            "Lat": 13,
            "Lon": 122,
            "Sender": "DX0HQ       "
        }
    },
    {
        "Band": "20",
        "Date": "Sat Jul 10 12:01:00 2021",
        "Receiver": {
            "Lat": 36.400001525878906,
            "Lon": 138.3800048828125,
            "Receiver": "JA1CJP      "
        },
        "Sender": {
            "Lat": 13,
            "Lon": 122,
            "Sender": "DX0HQ       "
        }
    }]
```

I hope this speeds up someone else's progression on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, many JSON C++ libraries have APIs that are non trivial to use, while JSON was intended to be easy to use.

So I tried [jsoncpp](http://www.genivia.com/doc/xml-rpc-json/html/index.html) from the [gSOAP tools](http://www.genivia.com/tutorials.html) on the JSON doc shown in one of the answers above and this is the code generated with jsoncpp to construct a JSON object in C++ which is then written in JSON format to std::cout:

```
value x(ctx);
x["appDesc"]["description"] = "SomeDescription";
x["appDesc"]["message"] = "SomeMessage";
x["appName"]["description"] = "Home";
x["appName"]["message"] = "Welcome";
x["appName"]["imp"][0] = "awesome";
x["appName"]["imp"][1] = "best";
x["appName"]["imp"][2] = "good";
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

and this is the code generated by jsoncpp to parse JSON from std::cin and extract its values (replace `USE_VAL` as needed):

```
value x(ctx);
std::cin >> x;
if (x.soap->error)
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // error parsing JSON
#define USE_VAL(path, val) std::cout << path << " = " << val << std::endl
if (x.has("appDesc"))
{
  if (x["appDesc"].has("description"))
    USE_VAL("$.appDesc.description", x["appDesc"]["description"]);
  if (x["appDesc"].has("message"))
    USE_VAL("$.appDesc.message", x["appDesc"]["message"]);
}
if (x.has("appName"))
{
  if (x["appName"].has("description"))
    USE_VAL("$.appName.description", x["appName"]["description"]);
  if (x["appName"].has("message"))
    USE_VAL("$.appName.message", x["appName"]["message"]);
  if (x["appName"].has("imp"))
  {
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < x["appName"]["imp"].size(); i2++)
      USE_VAL("$.appName.imp[]", x["appName"]["imp"][i2]);
  }
}
```

This code uses the JSON C++ API of gSOAP 2.8.28. I don't expect people to change libraries, but I think this comparison helps to put JSON C++ libraries in perspective.

Answer (score 1):

An example on how to use that would be great. There is a couple of examples at the [Qt forum](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/52857-reading-JSON-file-in-Qt5), but you're right that the official documentation should be expanded.

`QJsonDocument` on its own indeed doesn't produce anything, you will have to add the data to it. That's done through the `QJsonObject`, `QJsonArray` and `QJsonValue` classes. The top-level item needs to be either an array or an object (because `1` is not a valid json document, while `{foo: 1}` is.)

Comment: After looking into this, I think I'm gonna stay with QSettings instead of using JSon for certain things.  Thanks for your help.