# How to save and load a QJsonDocument to a file?

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5

I am trying to learn how to use **JSON** and the **Qt JSON classes**. For example I wnat to create a simple `QJsonDocument`, save it to a file, load it into a different `QJsonDocument` and compare results.

I managed to create a `QJsonDocument`. However there is no simple command in the `QJsonDocument` [interface](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qjsondocument.html) to save it to a file. The same goes for **loading** the document from a file.

```
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QVariant>

int main()
{
    QVariantMap map;
    map.insert("integer", 1);
    map.insert("double", 2.34);
    map.insert("bool", QVariant(true));
    map.insert("string", "word");
    QJsonObject object = QJsonObject::fromVariantMap(map);

    QJsonDocument document;
    document.setObject(object);

    // ?? save document to file
    // ?? load file to document

    return 0;
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18770335/1097451) shows how to load the document by

1. reading to a `QFile`
2. converting `QFile` to a `QString`
3. converting the `QString` to a `QByteArray`
4. constructing the `QJsonDocument` from the `QByteArray`

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for converting to string and back. With [QSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsettings.html) and [QVariant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvariant.html) classes you can easily do that. Create `QVariant` object from `QJsonDocument` and save it with `QSettings`. Look at functions [QJsonDocument::fromVariant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qjsondocument.html#fromVariant) and [QJsonDocument::toVariant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qjsondocument.html#toVariant). Combine them with `QSettings` class and specifically [void QSettings::setValue ( const QString & key, const QVariant & value )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#setValue) method, that works well with `QVariant` and that's it.

Also `QSettings` class has this constructor [QSettings::QSettings ( const QString & fileName, Format format, QObject * parent = 0 )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#QSettings-4) 
 that would allow you to set path to the file - `fileName` variable

Comment: Please could you explain a little more? How can I use the QSettings to save a QVariant into a file? AFAIK QSettings saves application settings to a determined platform-specific location and not to a file.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik i've edited answer. You can construct QSettings object and open from the location you want. Also QSetting class stores all it's values in QVariant, and that's exactly what we need with QJsonDocument.

Comment: But `void QSettings::setValue(const QString & key, const QVariant & value )` will save the data into the `.conf` folder or the Windows registry or to a different location over which I have no control. How can I save the `QJsonDocument` to let's say `object.json` in a specific folder?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik yes, there is scecific constructor in QSettings for that purpose, edited answer, http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#QSettings-4 . You can set path and format yourself

Comment: I am sorry, I am not very familiar with QSettings. Can an application have several settings in different locations? Doesn't this break the other settings?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik of course not, it should not break it. Though, you can just use one QSetting file, with different keys. But as long as you create different QSettings objects for different settings files, there really shoud not be any trouble at all

Comment: @MartinDrozdik the constructor, that i've suggested will just create file, that is not specific for application, you can create and read dozens of them, just treat them like the usual files

Comment: This is some convoluted advice. Why go through `QSettings`? The straightforward way is to use `document.toJson()` to get the UTF-8 encoded Json text.

Comment: @KubaOber and why go through QFile if QSettings is exactly for cases such is this? And IMO `toVariant` and `fromVariant` combine with QSettings way better, then constantly reading and flushing text to files by hands.

Comment: @Shf: QSettings will store the json as the string (or binary!) value of a key in the .ini format. That's braindead at best. When reading such a file, QSettings has to parse the value out of it. It just makes no sense at all to use QSettings for this. It sounds to me like you haven't actually used it, and haven't looked at the generated file.

Comment: @KubaOber let us not assume, what i used and what did not, ok? For a start, why save json in a file in a first place if not to restore data on application relaunch. I don't see another reason, that's why i suggested QSettings, now, what is your reason? In what case you would need to store json in a file and when dances with QFile would be more easier then QSettings?

Comment: @Shf: The question is about a json file, not about settings. It's you who assume that it's used to store settings. If one wants to store settings, there's no point to json at all, simply use QSettings directly. Why add another layer of indirection?

Answer (score 51):

Personally, I think that code [that you linked to] looks a bit messy. Warning: head compiled code follows.

```
QJsonDocument loadJson(QString fileName) {
    QFile jsonFile(fileName);
    jsonFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    return QJsonDocument().fromJson(jsonFile.readAll());
}

void saveJson(QJsonDocument document, QString fileName) {
    QFile jsonFile(fileName);
    jsonFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly);
    jsonFile.write(document.toJson());
}
```

This may not be perfect: it assumes `QFile` instead of `QIODevice`, but if you're dealing with only local files maybe it won't matter. You can then use these functions instead of repeating the Json load/save code everytime you need to load/save Json.

Comment: Thank you! The two answers are equally valuable to me

Comment: I learn by example a lot quicker personally, so I like this answer _more_, but yeah, they're both quite good!

Comment: From a memory point of view this is not the best, because the json is first loaded from file into memory as a QByteArray and then the byte array is parsed to produce the Json document. So you get a spike from holding raw text and Json in memory at once. On a PC this doesn't matter, but it matters a lot when memory is constrained. It might be more efficient to QFile::map() the file into memory and then use QByteArray::fromRawData on it.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could post this with an example as an alternative answer @locka