# Can I use JavaScript to get JSON data from the server inside my qt app?

Tags: qt, qml

I need to get JSON data and load it to a table. As I guess I need some C++ skills for it. But can I do this in plain JavaScript or may be QML?

Comment: @sashoalm seriously!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can do it purely using javascript API's in QML. Following code works on Qt 5.3.1

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 400

    ListModel {
        id: model
    }

    ListView {
        id: listview
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: model
        delegate: Text {
            text: listdata
        }
    }

    function getData() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_MYSQL.php";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function myFunction(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            listview.model.append( {listdata: arr[i].Name +" "+ arr[i].City +" "+ arr[i].Country })
        }
    }

    Button {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        width: parent.width
        text: "Get Data"
        onClicked: getData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped a lot. Please edit your answer. Some parts of your code aren't marked as code.

Comment: I have actually added the code inside the code tags, but its not formatting it properly. Thanks.

Comment: You can format it easily by adding a 4 spaced tab setting to your editor and adding an extra tab before the whole code, then copy paste it here, as I just did

Comment: Thanks islahul, i'll remember this next time. I'm a newb here :)

Comment: the disadvantage is the javascript part won't be compiled natively, so it's not good from a security perspective. If it's something important.

Answer (score 3):

If you add the pure-QML [JSONListModel](https://github.com/kromain/qml-utils) to your project, you can use the full power of the View-Model pattern. However, it doesn't support presenting the data before it is fully downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that easily in C++ as Qt5 has native support for JSON. Check the following answer for the example:

[How to create/read/write JSon files in Qt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893040/how-to-create-read-write-json-files-in-qt5)

Comment: If you would read the question more carefully you understand that I want a javascript/qml solution not C++ one.