# Parsing JSON starting with bracket `[` with Qt5

Tags: c++, json, qt, parsing, qt5

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034444/can-a-json-start-with), A JSON starting with bracket is valid, so i have encoded a list of item, in a `test.json` file:

```
[{"name": "a"},{"name": "b"}]
```

Heavily inspirated by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18770335/3077939), i push this code in `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      // Reading the JSON, parse it, get data as QJsonObject
      QString val;
      QFile file;
      file.setFileName("test.json");
      file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
      val = file.readAll();
      file.close();
      QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val.toUtf8());
      QJsonObject sett2 = d.object();

      // Printings
      qWarning() << "File content: " << val;
      qWarning() << "sett2: " << sett2 << " (empty: " << sett2.empty() << ')';

      // try to access the data directly
      QJsonValue value = sett2.value(QString("name"));
      qWarning() << "name value: " << value;
      QJsonObject item = value.toObject();
      qWarning() << "QJsonObject of accessed value: " << item;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
File content: "[{\"name\": \"a\"},{\"name\": \"b\"}]\n"
sett2:  QJsonObject()  (empty:  true )
name value: QJsonValue(undefined)
QJsonObject of accessed value:  QJsonObject()
```

We see that the file is properly readed. However, no data seems to be accessed : `sett2` is empty, as if holding no data.

After searching on the [QJsonObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html) documentation, i can't found any routine that can give access to the data in the file, in this case: the only one that seems to allow an access to fields is the `value()`, method, but it needs a parameter.
Call it with `0`, `1`, `NULL` `"name"`, `"a"`, `"b"` and `"knock knock"` lead to compilation error or empty data.
Other methods, like `keys()`, returns also empty data.

How access data of objects ? (here, `name: "a"` and `name: "b"`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answere is simple - you have to call [`QJsonDocument::array()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#array) instead of `object`:

```
QJsonArray sett2 = d.array();
```