# How to convert a QJsonObject to QString

Tags: qt, qstring, qjsonobject

I have a QJsonObject data and want to convert to QString. How can I do this? Searched for help in Qt, it only can convert QJsonObject to QVariantMap...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The class you're looking for is QJsonDocument: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Remembering when I first needed to do this, the documentation can be a bit lacking and assumes you have knowledge of other QJson classes.

To obtain a QString of a QJsonObject, you need to use the QJsonDocument class, like this: -

```
QJsonObject jsonObj; // assume this has been populated with Json data

QJsonDocument doc(jsonObj);
QString strJson(doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact));
```

Comment: It should probably be mentioned, that `QJsonDocument::toJson()` returns a UTF-8 formatted `QByteArray`.

Answer (score 6):

we can do this in one line

```
QString strFromObj = QJsonDocument(jsonObject).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact).toStdString().c_str();
```

Comment: Or just
`QString strFromObj = QJsonDocument(jsonObject).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);`

Answer (score 0):

When the macro `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII` is enabled, you can do something like:

```
QJsonDocument doc(jsonObject);
QByteArray docByteArray = doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
Qstring strJson = codec->toUnicode(docByteArray);
```

Or better, just use `QLatin1String(QByteArray&)`, based on the example of [TheDarkKnight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28191005/2522849):

```
QJsonDocument doc(jsonObj);
QByteArray docByteArray = doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);
Qstring strJson = QLatin1String(docByteArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

QJsonDocument doc;
...
doc.toVariant().toString();