# QT what are the QML/C++ data types which can be converted to JSON?

Tags: javascript, c++, json, qt

According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-javascript.html

> Furthermore keep in mind that only QML/C++ data types which can be converted to JSON will be (de-)serialized properly and thus accessible to HTML clients.

What are those data types which can be converted to JSON? 
Is the QJsonObject or QJsonDocument included on it?

Comment: The web page says 

> The transport object implements a minimal message passing interface.
> It should be an object with a send() function, which takes a
> stringified JSON message and transmits it to the server-side

It would appear you have to roll your own JSON and send it to and from the server.

Comment: Qt provices a propper wrapper. But something happens before it that takes the raw data (int, string, etc) and transforms it in a QJson object to send it later using the  wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into the documentation for classes such as [QJsonValue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html) and [QJsonObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html) and see which types and classes can be used by constructors or by from*(...) functions, which are usually static and ask for a QVariant/QVariantHash/QVariantMap.

Given that in Qt JavaScript an array can be converted into a QList<> and an object to a QVariantMap, I would guess those (and basic types such as int, float, string...) should be passed to the C++ side and made into QJson(Value/Object/Array) then.

Depending on what you want, a QJsonObject could be, for example, formatted as a string like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28191005/5508057). For further information, [JSON support in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html).

Comment: sorry, this is not what im looking for, Im not trying to create QJson objects, but passing them by signal args.