# Qt http bad request on google

Tags: c++, api, qt, httprequest

I'm trying to create an url shortener app using google's url shortener api (https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#shorten). The problem is that I get a bad request.
Here is the error: 
**Error: Error downloading https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url - server replied: Bad Request**

What did I do wrong?
Here is the code:

```
void MainWindow::ppp(QString longurl)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));

    QUrl url = QUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url");

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setHeader(request.ContentTypeHeader,"application/json");

    QByteArray postData;
    postData.append("longUrl");
    postData.append(longurl);


    manager->post(request,postData);
}

void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        ui->textBrowser->setText("Error: " +  reply->errorString());
    }
    else
    {
        QByteArray responseData = reply->readAll();
        QString qstr(responseData);
        ui->textBrowser->setText(qstr);
    }
}
```

Comment: anyone? #shortcomment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send your post data in json format.

To make your code work, replace

```
QByteArray postData;
postData.append("longUrl");
postData.append(longurl);
```

with this

```
QByteArray postData;
postData.append("{\"longUrl\": \""+longurl+"\"}");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
request.setHeader(request.ContentTypeHeader,"Content-Type: application/json");
```

Should be:

```
request.setHeader(request.ContentTypeHeader,"application/json");
```

And:

Youre sending json data. (Your header says so) So ypu have to format the postData as json.
Also, you will have to set content-length.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12487795/1829897)

Comment: Edited again, Check it. You have to format your post data as json. Sorry

Comment: Don't think wou can. Youll have to get the full json response and parse it for the info you want. Check http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/json.html for qt5 / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169988/easiest-way-to-parse-json-in-qt-4-7 for qt4